# Run Unix commands from Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, linux, bash, terminal

I would like to run Lynis (audit tool preinstalled in Kali Linux) from a webpage using  javascript technology but  I don’t know how to execute local programs using bash commands from Javascript, can somebody help me?

In short, the general idea is the following:

1. The visitor (let’s assume the visitor is using Kali Linux on his computer with Lynis installed) enters to my webpage www.example.com/example.html
2. The visitor downloads the content of the page and with a button or something similar we can execute shell commands and run Lynis software on the visitor's computer. (e.g. "# sudo lynis")
3. When Lynis finishes its execution the generated results in some way interacts with the javascript code and we can show this information on the website.

(The priority now is point 1 and 2)

Thanks in advance.

P.S. If this is not possible ... is there any way to do this without using javascript?

Comment: what if I do `sudo rm -r /` ? no, not possible without an assistance of extraordinary naive user.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I found examples where do something similar.

e.g. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/626644/HTML-Run-a-client-program-from-a-web-page)

But this is for Windows and IE...I want a similar approach for Unix systems and Chrome! @webduvet

Comment: Have the web page include a shell script that the user can download and review.  Have that shell script generate HTML from the final results and the user can open it in his web browser of choice.  Alternatively, have the script generate some report format and let the user upload the resulting report file to your website and you can parse it and let them interact with it there.

Comment: I don't think it's prossible to do from a browser, maybe through ActiveX components but it's not a standard thing (and probably not available on Linux).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible or it would be the largest security hole ever.

Comment: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/626644/HTML-Run-a-client-program-from-a-web-page) I want something similar but for Unix Systems + Chrome/Firefox

Comment: Other than ActiveX (which is a MS thing) I doubt you'll find support for this anywhere else as it's a deprecated feature. You can only find it on IE browsers and it's being dropped out of Edge.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript code can easily be injected and altered by the user since it is a client side language. That means it is stored and executed on their browser, and it is neither encrypted nor compiled so it can be viewed and edited at their leisure. This means simply having JavaScript be able to execute server-side shell commands would a massive security hole.

That being said, you could create a PHP script that executes a shell command which you could call using JavaScript. Again, remember that this opens a huge security hole.

The JavaScript:

```
function exec(command) {

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("action","exec.php");
    form.setAttribute("method","post");
    form.setAttribute("display","none");

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type","text");
    input.setAttribute("name","command");
    input.value = command;
    form.appendChild(input);

    var submit = document.createElement("input");
    submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
    form.appendChild(submit);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    submit.click();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

The PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["command"])) 
    shell_exec($_POST["command"]);  
print "<script>history.go(-1)</script>"
```

The PHP goes in a file called "exec.php" and the JavaScript can be put in any webpage you want it to work with.

You can then execute a shell command on your computer via JavaScript simply by using the "exec" function. Such as "exec('gedit')" will open gedit on my computer.

If you use this, *any* user who logs into your website can type that command and execute commands on your computer.